# Weighed Graph C - segfault

Tags: c, memory, graph, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make my own Weighed Graph structure, basing on struct scheme found in net but for some reason i get segfault when I try to execute the code, debugger said that issue is in AddVertex method but unfortunetly, i cannot find it by myself.

```
 #ifndef graph_h
#define graph_h


typedef struct graphCDT
         *graphADT;


typedef struct vertexTag {
      char *element;
      int visited;
      struct edgeTag *edges;
      struct vertexTag *next;
} vertexT;

typedef struct edgeTag {
     int weight;
     struct vertexTag *connectsTo;
     struct edgeTag *next;
} edgeT;

typedef struct graphCDT {
     vertexT *vertices;
} graphCDT;

#endif


#include "graph.h"
#include "dbg.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int RecIsReachable(void *dest,
                          vertexT *startP)
{
  edgeT *edgeP;


  if (startP->visited)
    return 0;


  if (startP->element == dest)
    return 1;


  startP->visited = 1;


  for (edgeP = startP->edges;
           edgeP != NULL;
           edgeP = edgeP->next) {
    if (RecIsReachable(dest, edgeP->connectsTo))
      return 1;
  }


  return 0;
}


int GraphIsReachable(graphADT graph,
                     void *dest,
                     void *source)
{
  vertexT *vertP;
  vertexT *startP = NULL;


  for (vertP = graph->vertices;
           vertP != NULL;
           vertP = vertP->next) {
    vertP->visited = 0;
    if (vertP->element == source)
      startP = vertP;
  }


  if (startP == NULL)
    return 0;


  return RecIsReachable(dest, startP);
}






void AddVertex(graphADT graph, char *element) {

     if(graph == NULL) {
         graph = calloc(1, sizeof(graphADT));
         graph->vertices->element = element;
     } else {

     vertexT *temp = graph->vertices;
     vertexT *n =  calloc(1,sizeof(graphADT));
     n->element = element;

     while(temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        }

      temp->next = n;
      n->next = NULL;
     }
}

void AddEdge(graphADT graph,
             int w,
             char *elem1,
             char *elem2) {



      vertexT *to = graph->vertices;
      vertexT *from = graph->vertices;


      while(to != NULL) {
               to = to->next;
               if(to->element == elem2) {
                       break;
               }
         }

        while(from != NULL) {
               from = from->next;
               if(from->element == elem1) {
                       break;
               }
         }
       check(to->element == elem2, "Unnable to found graph which contains elem2");
       check(from->element == elem1, "Unnable to found graph which contains elem1");

      edgeT *temp = from->edges;
      edgeT *temp2 = to->edges;

      while(temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
      }
      temp->connectsTo = to;
      temp->weight = w;

      while(temp2 != NULL) {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
      }
      temp2->connectsTo = from;
      temp2->weight = w;
error:
   return;

}
int main()
{
    char *test1 = "p";
    char *test2 = "d";
    char *test3 = "t";
    char *test4 = "w";
    char *test5 = "s";
    char *test6 = "x";

    graphADT graph = NULL;
    AddVertex(graph, test1);
    AddVertex(graph, test2);
    AddVertex(graph, test3);
    AddVertex(graph, test4);
    AddVertex(graph, test5);
    AddVertex(graph, test6);

    AddEdge(graph,2,test1, test2);
    AddEdge(graph,3,test1, test3);
    AddEdge(graph,4,test2, test4);
    AddEdge(graph,5,test5,test1);
    AddEdge(graph,6,test6, test3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this type implementation

```
void ResizeGraph(struct Graph *g) {
    g->array = realloc(g->array , g->v+1);
    if(!g->array) {
        printf("Memory Error");
        return;
    }
    g->array[g->v].head = NULL;
    g->v = g->v+1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your *graphCDT* structure has a pointer to *vertexT* structure, but you forgot to allocate memory for it before using. Add `graph->vertices = calloc(1, sizeof(vertexT));` to *AddVertex* function:

```
void AddVertex(graphADT graph, char *element) {
     if(graph == NULL) {
         graph = calloc(1, sizeof(graphADT));
         graph->vertices = calloc(1, sizeof(vertexT));
         graph->vertices->element = element;
     } else {
     <...>
```

Just a quick look, there might be similar errors elsewhere, hope you get an idea to find them by yourself.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(graphADT)` in the first `calloc()` is wrong; that's the size of the pointer, not the size of the structure. As the structure is currently defined, the two sizes may be the same, but it's still a logic error.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try it. I thought that allocating memory for struct that contains other structures deals with each of them and additional allocating isn't necessary.

Comment: Allocating memory for `graph` does allocate space for the `vertices` member, but it only allocates space for _the pointer itself_; it doesn't allocate a second block of memory to which `vertices` can point.